# 3gb File upload php

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to upload an 2.6gb file to my server. It is using the Dropzone JS upload script. The uploading seems to go well, however the server can't find the file in the final directory.

Current php.ini settings are:

```
file_uploads On
max_file_uploads 20
max_execution_time -1 (i know this is bad, only for testing)
memory_limit -1 (i know this is bad, only for testing)
upload_max_filesize 53687091200M
post_max_size 53687091200M
```

Server has 4gb memory and 3 processing cores.

Could it be related to the fact that I only have 4gb of memory that it can't copy the file from tmp to final destination? As 2x2,6 > 4?

1.5 gb files seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your dropzone config.  Make sure you have explicitly given it both a timeout value and a maxFilesize value.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(
    "#filedrag", {
        url: "../post-files.php",
        autoProcessQueue: 'false',
        autoQueue: 'true',
        createImageThumbnails: 'false',
        previewsContainer: '#previews',
        uploadMultiple: 'true',
        maxFilesize: '1000000000000',
        timeout: '60000000',
        paramName: "file",
        init: function(){
            ....
        }
    }
);
```